# GCM demo server

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have run the GCM client demo application from the Android developers site.

Now I just want to know whether there is a server just to test if the application works. I do not want to build my own server, I just want to test the application.

By the way I am working on Eclipse and trying to develop an application for Android.

Answer (score 2):

> I do not want to build my own server, I just want to test the application.

You do not need a server. You need something that will send messages to the GCM servers. In production, that is typically a server, but it does not have to be.

For example, [this Java project and associated shell script](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Push/GCMCommand) implements a command-line GCM utility that sends messages to designated registration IDs. There may be other such utilities available from other sources.

Comment: I downloaded it, if I have any questions I will ask you, thanks

Comment: I cannot import the command into eclipse

Comment: +1 great tool Mark - really quick for debugging my GCM!

Comment: btw for anyone who cant work this its a command-line tool as mark methods - run via the `gcm` bash script (this sets up the classpath and forwards the args). example execution `./gcm -a AIzaSyACYgiUOkFMCiz1qGp4adhQ9cdCQ84o-wI -D test -d APA91bFQqVWhf--PHR_--OGSv5sPs8uBh0aGLs1uo_Exy5Rrh_ZyKFdpBr827RpLwGVLwcTGS-jLtJbr_rtTYxiZuyeyTY-RCJru9uYN8hOt622sJa6MGMjicnd6PkHVhM7GrJzNmovW68NL9RapYAixn2iQbZXBlw`

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy [this](https://github.com/tttzof351/gsm-test-server) server on google app engine for testing gcm.

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer, because the link also has a deployed demo with a given sender ID

Comment: Link is dead (that's why link-answers are discouraged)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a very simple to use GCM test server that is implemented as a maven plugin.
It is part of the GCMUtils project, see here for more information: https://code.google.com/p/gcmutils/wiki/MavenPlugin#Test_server